# Удаление названия столбца индексов в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Загружаю файл CSV. Восстанавливаю значения индексов из столбца "Unnamed: 0". Индексы восстанавливаются, но над ними появляется название столбца индексов: "Unnamed: 0". Далее я хочу уничтожить это название (т.е. "Unnamed: 0"). Но не знаю как. У меня ничего не выходит. Это возможно?

```
test_load = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
test_load = test_load.set_index('Unnamed: 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот одно из решений:

```
test_load.index.name = None
```